# How would you implement something like a 2-way map?

Tags: c++, std

I want some sort of container that gives me a 2-way map between integers and strings.

I give it an int, and it gives me the string associated with it.

I give it the string, and it gives me the int associated with it .

How would you implement such a thing?

Comment: Depend on the range of integer part, maybe vector + map.

Comment: If you can afford to use Boost, there's [Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) ready-made.

Comment: It's often referred to as a bimap or a bijection map. Googling it should give you some existing code.

Comment: Do you have performance requirements? If not, copying std::map and adding some logic to enforce unique values and to iterator over values until a specific value is found then return its key.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 maps for that and as you add/remove to those maps, make sure they are in sync. I don't know how to do it with only one container.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class with two maps:

```
class BiMap {

    void insert( string const & s, int i ) {
        stringToInt[ s ] = i;
        intToString[ i ] = s;
    }

    int find( string const & s ) const {
        // use stringToInt[ s ];     
    }

    string find( int const & i ) const {
        // use intToString[ i ];     
    }

    map< string, int >   stringToInt;
    map< int, string >   intToString;
};
```